# Round corner CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a scenario where I have to create the button on Asp:LinkButton. I have create the button on it.

Now I want to set the round corner on this button. Please, tell me the CSS solution to round the button..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rounded corners can be done in standard CSS in all browsers except IE.

```
.rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

The good news is that there is an excellent hack for IE called [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com) that brings it into line, meaning that you can use CSS `border-radius` in all browsers. (CSS3Pie hack even works for IE6! although IE6 has enough other issues that I still wouldn't touch it with a bargepole)

Answer (score 0):

```
.border {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Its Firefox and Chrome only.

Comment: Sorry @Danjah but I'm going to have to down-vote this.  Its not acceptable these days to have browser specific techniques

Comment: I disagree, its dependent on the situation - downvote accepted because I appreciate your opinion.

Comment: Replace the `-webkit-border-radius` by `border-radius`. Safari and Chrome no longer need the prefix, and Opera and IE9 will also work that way.

Comment: `border-radius` is *not* browser specific; it's standard CSS and works in all browsers other than IE. It can be even made to work in IE with a bit of persuasion; See my answer for more.